# How to create and save new workbook from UserForm?

Tags: vba

I'm currently attempting to write code in VBA that creates and saves a new workbook based on user input. I have a macro to create the workbook, and I have code for the command button on the UserForm. I am currently getting an "object required" error, and it seems like the projname and projnum variables aren't even being assigned the values I want them to be. It seems like there are issues with either or both the variable assignment and the saving of the file.

Module 1:

```
Public projname As String
Public projnum As String

Sub createWB()

    Dim uf2 As New UserForm2
    uf2.Show

    Set outputWorkbook = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Wk.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Public\Desktop\" & projname & ".xlsx"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

UserForm Module:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    projname = UserForm2.TextBox1.Text
    projnum = UserForm2.TextBox2.Text
    Me.Hide
    Unload UserForm2

End Sub
```

Comment: How/ where are you calling `createWB`? Also use `Debug.Print` in `createWB` to test if your string contain text.

Comment: You should be able to know for sure where the errors are coming from by placing a breakpoint and stepping through your code. You can consult [this guide](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code) if you're not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is easy: Instead of `projname = UserForm2.TextBox1.Text`, write `projname = Me.TextBox1.Text`

The explanation is a little more complicated. A userform in VBA is a class, and if you want to use an instance of that class, it needs to be created. You create a userform-object in your `CreateWB`-routine with the statement `Dim uf2 As New UserForm2` (the `new` will create it).

Most people are lazy and don't do that, instead they just write `UserForm2.show()`. So there is no statement to *create* the form-object, but the form is displayed anyhow. What happens in the background is that the VBA runtime will check if a so called *default instance* of that class exists. If not, it will create it on the fly. Your program can access this default instance by the name of the class (eg with the name `UserForm2`, that contains an object of type `UserForm2`).

Remember, in your `createWB`-routine, you create your own object, so the *default instance* is not needed (and not created).

Now, as long as you are within the code of a class, you can access it's class members with the keyword `Me` (other languages use the keyword `this`). So to access the text of the control `TextBox1.text`, you can write `Me.TextBox1.text`.

If you are outside of the form (eg in `createWB`), you can access the members with `uf2.TextBox1.text` - but only if the instance of uf2 is valid. If you use the command `Unload`, it will destroy the object and you will get a runtime error.

In your button-click event, you used `UserForm2.TextBox1.Text`, and now something unexpected happens: The default instance of `UserForm2` don't exists at that time, so VBA creates it. That is a *new* (invisble) instance of the class, and of course the textboxes are not filled. So you write empty strings into `projname` and `projnum`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation! I'm more familiar with Java than I am with VBA, so I am familiar with the concept of classes, this, etc... Your fix did successfully assign the string to the variable, but the SaveAs line is still giving the object required error. Any ideas?

Comment: probably you mean `outputWorkbook.SaveAs` ? `Wk` seems undefined. Btw: do you have `Option Explicit` at the top of your code?

Comment: I totally missed that! I was changing my variable from Wk to outputWorkbook and forgot to change it there. I am now getting a path error though. I am trying to save it to the desktop.

Comment: This is the reason to put `Option Explicit` at the top - you will immediately see such errors as the compiler will complain.

Comment: Do you have write access to `C:\Users\Public` (this is the desktop for all users and is usually write proteced)? Try to use `Filename:=environ("userprofile") & "\Desktop\" & projname & ".xlsx" to access your own desktop